# Enumerating questions with using numbers

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I am using the `beamer` package and I am writing a lot of questions. I am answering each question and each question is enumerated, so when I add another question, I need to put the number manually. Each question has its answer and at some point in the future it has to have its medium-sized comment. Bear in mind that I want to add any question without worrying about the order of the questions and without changing the number, just like when I add a equation anywhere in my document and latex enumerates it without problem. I don't know if it is worth using the `enumerate` package (there are many questions) o if there is a trick (maybe a counter). How do I solve this?

**Edit**: My code is:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title[]{Actividad de la novena}
\date{Diciembre 22 de 2014} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{}
    1. Por primera vez en la historia de la humanidad, un módulo de aterrizaje aterriza     en un cometa para estudiarlo. ¿Cuándo ocurrió este hecho?
    \end{block}

    \begin{enumerate}[a)]
        \item El 5 de noviembre.
        \item El 12 de noviembre.
        \item El 29 de octubre.
        \item El 25 de octubre
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
2. Dicho módulo de aterrizaje no iba solo, él se desprendió de una sonda espacial     que lo acompañaba. ¿Cuáles son los nombres del módulo y de la sonda?
\end{block}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item Philae y Orión. 
    \item Orión y Rosetta.
    \item Philae y Rosetta.
    \item Orión y Lutecia.
\end{enumerate}

 \end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
3. ¿Cuándo ocurrió la segunda vuelta presidencial?
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
4. Si solo tomamos en cuenta listas abiertas, ¿cuál fue el segundo senador con más     votos en el país?
\end{block}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item Musa Besaile. 
    \item Horacio Serpa.
    \item Jorge Enrique Robledo.
    \item Bernando Elías.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be really great if you could show us an example of your setup. This way we can see what you use for a question and an answer. It will aid in providing you with a better solution to your current situation.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve with regard to the questions' numbers. Would you like to questions to be numbered automatically and consecutively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using a new `question` counter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{question}
\newcommand\question[1]{\stepcounter{question}Q.~\arabic{question} -- #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame one}
  \question{Where is my first question?}

  \question{What is my second question?}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame two}

  \question{Who is my third question?}

  \question{When is my fourth question?}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If your document requires labeled questions (and cross-referenced via `\ref`), you may use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`